# How do I process a string array in curl with java spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc, curl

I want to implement a postmapping method called process that receives this kind of call:

```
curl -d '["a", "b", "c"]' "http://localhost:8080/process"
```

So I implemented ta method with the following template:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
List process(@RequestBody String[] list) {
    ...
}
```

> But I got an exception.  HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content
>   type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported.

If I remove the `@RequestBody` my list variable will just be null. Can anyone help me?